# Unnest json string array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I'm using psql and I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | dashboard_settings
-----------------------
 1 | {"query": {"year_end": 2018, "year_start": 2015, "category": ["123"]}}
```

There are numerous rows, but for every row the "category" value is an array with one integer (in string format).

Is there a way I can 'unpackage' the category object? So that it just has 123 as an integer?

I've tried this but had no success:

```
SELECT jsonb_extract_path_text(dashboard_settings->'query', 'category') from table
```

This returns:

```
jsonb_extract_path_text | ["123"]
```

when I want:

```
jsonb_extract_path_text | 123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the array access operator for which is simply `->>` followed by the array index:

```
select jsonb_extract_path(dashboard_settings->'query', 'category') ->> 0
from the_table
```

alternatively:

```
select dashboard_settings -> 'query' -> 'category' ->> 0
from the_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
select dashboard_settings->'query'->'category'->>0 c from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4e76f1cceb399ed5ac0c2dc4a2c04275)**:

```
| c   |
| :-- |
| 123 |
```